# Switching Product Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to form a `query` which should identify give me a list of customers who made a product switch over the months.
I've a dataset as below:

```
Transaction_ID  Customer    Product     Date
--------------  --------    --------    ------
1001            Cust1       Prod1       01-Jan-13
2234            Cust1       Prod2       15-Mar-13
2523            Cust1       Prod1       18-Mar-13
.................................................
8238            Cust1       Prod2       09-Jun-13
9127            Cust1       Prod2       18-Jun-13
```

It should give me the id `'Cust1'` as `Cust1` used to buy more prod1 before and then switched to Prod2. I'm not sure whether I should use self join. Please help. (I'm using Oracle 11G)

Comment: To write an appropriate SQL is not the real problem right now. To define what time ranges to compare and when exactly to consider a product to be switched is the task. A task only you can solve. Cust1 bought Prod1, but then switched to Prod2 and then back to Prod1, but you don't consider these "switches". Why not? Only later, when Cust1 bought Prod2 two times within few days, you consider this a product switch. Why now?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you're right! If we consider a time span of 1-year, then I'd like to know who all switched from Prod1 to Prod2; switching can start at any time within this 1-year duration. 
Let's assume in period 1 the customer bought Prod1 more than 75% of times, and in period 2 she bought Prod2 more than 75% of times. (We don't know the value of period 1 and period 2)
And there are other complexities as well. For example, we should capture only those customers who are switching from Prod1 to Prod2, not vice versa (In which case below query
by doker will not be applicable).

Comment: Do you mean period 1 and period 2 have to be 1 year each? In which case would you need to wait until you had data to at least 18th March 2014 to indicate Cust1 had switched to Prod2 above? I don't think that is your intention, but then you need to specify how long period 1 and period 2 have to be, to ensure that e.g. the Prod2 purchase on 15-Mar-13 above does not count as a switch.

Comment: @user3804238: The rules are still not completely specified. In January Cust1 bought 100% Prod1. Then suddenly he/she switched to buy 100% Prod2. For some days. Then on March 18 it turned out he/she bought Prod1 again. So for three days we detected a product switch, but since March 18 we don't consider it to be one anymore. Another look on the data: From January to mid June they bought 50% Prod1 and 50% Prod2, but since mid June they bought 100% Prod2. You see, it all depends how you shift the time ranges you look at. So again: Find the rules to apply.

Comment: Total timespan is 1 year and period 1 can be from Jan to May(or any time in between) and Period 2 can be the next month to the rest of the time period. But I understand the difficulty of having varied time frame like this, so let's say period 1 is first six months and period 2 starts from 7th month onwards.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Well that's just a representative data, just like there are lot of customers not just Cust1 and Cust2. I'd like to know who all bought Prod1 more than 75% of their total purchase during Jan to June and then from July onwards buying Prod2 more than 75% of time. I'm sorry for all the confusion, as rules are at very early stage!

Comment: So a switch from Jul-Dec 13 to Jan-Jun 14 is not to be considered. But both Jan-Jun 12 / Jul-Dec 12 and Jan-Jun 13 / Jul-Dec 13 must be checked. Correct?

Comment: Let's just consider only Jan-Jun 13 (Period 1) and Jul - Dec 13 (Period 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now that you reduced the task such as to simply find customers who's Prod1 purchase in Jan-Jun 2013 made up more than 75% and whose Prod2 purchase in Jul-Dec 2013 made up more than 75%, too, we can build two sets and intersect.

```
select customer
from transaction
where extract(year from tdate) = 2013 and extract(month from tdate) <= 6
group by customer
having sum(case when product = 'Prod1' then 1 end) / count(*) > 0.75
intersect
select customer
from transaction
where extract(year from tdate) = 2013 and extract(month from tdate) > 6
group by customer
having sum(case when product = 'Prod2' then 1 end) / count(*) > 0.75
```

Comment: Great, that's just what I wanted, Thanks a lot @Thorsten Kettner! And thanks for sticking to it despite poor specifications and help me streamline it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(Product) from (select Customer, Product from Table group by Customer, Product) group by Customer
```

Count > 1 ==> they made a switch.

Comment: You can reduce this to: `select customer from mytable group by customer having count(distinct product) > 1`.

Comment: this answer does not solve the question as it is currently posed - it will flag someone as switching if they buy Prod1 100 times, then Prod2 once, then Prod1 another 100 times. The questions allows people to buy more than 1 product, and is looking for them switching from predominantly buying Prod1 to predominantly buying Prod2.

Comment: Vague requirements. Please specify what does "product switch over the months" means exactly.